# Indentation of Sublists of Wide List

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

The `wide` feature of `enumitem` package effectively makes the item label part of the text, instead of setting the margin of the following text left of the label. I would like to use the `wide` feature, but I do not want this behavior in the case where a list item is immediately followed by another list:

[image]

Do you know how I can tweak the behavior of the list so that sublist items are intended correctly? I went through the manual and searched online, but could not find any information that I thought was relevant.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{test}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[test, 1]{label = (\alph*), wide = 0pt}
\setlist[test, 2]{label = \roman*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
\item
\begin{test}
\item This item is OK.
\item This item should be indented.
\item This item should be indented as well.
\end{test}
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution, if I uderstand well what you want, consists in making  the sublist `wide`, but with a left alignment. Here are two ways, differing  in the leftmargin of the sublist:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{test}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[test, 1]{label = (\alph*), wide = 0pt}
\setlist[test, 2]{label = \roman*., wide = 3em, align = right}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
\item \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep \relax}
\begin{test}
\item This item is OK.
\item This item \emph{is} indented.
\item This item is indented as well. This item is indented as well. This item is indented as well. This item is indented as well.
\end{test}
\item \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep \relax}
\begin{test}[ leftmargin = \dimexpr3em + \labelwidth + \labelsep\relax]
\item This item is OK.
\item This item \emph{is} indented.
\item This item is indented as well. This item is indented as well. This item is indented as well. This item is indented as well.
\end{test}
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering both of my questions about lists =) The solution works perfectly.